# How to save a list of variables whose names (as strings) are given?

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a bunch of numpy arrays, the names of which (as strings) are in a list:

mylist = ['arr1', 'arr2', ....]

I want to save them with np.save, all of them. What I tried:

```
for avar in mylist:
    np.save(avar+'.npy', exec(avar))
```

It works? IDK, at least there's no error, But, when later loaded, it throws this error:

> ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False

Would be nice if you show me how to load them later to same variable names.

Comment: How did you make this bunch?  Each with a separate name?  If you have a list of names, don't you also have a list of the arrays?  But  have you tried the `load` with `allow_pickle=True`?  What's the result?  Another thing to check is `exec('arr1')`.  Is that really the array you expect?

Comment: I solved the problem as shown in the answer section. Yes you're right, I do have the arrays themselves, but I just happen to be able to easily construct a list of their names as strings and I want to save them in a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

If all your variables are local, you can do

```
vars = locals()
for astring in mylist:
    np.save(astring + '.npy', vars[astring])
```

If you have some global variables as well, then do

```
vars = globals()
```

@Alex, if your variable names are coming in from the network or an external file, then you run the risk of arbitrary code execution with `exec`.

Comment: I hate that command. It returns mountains of rubbish and builtins  variables that I never created and even modules are returned. You have to sift through them to extract the "user-created" variables. At any rate, creating a dictionary for them is a great idea, like the one returned by locals(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it,

```
for astring in mylist:
    exec('tmp = ' + astring )
    np.save(astring + '.npy', tmp)
```

When restoring:

```
for astring in mylist:
    tmp = np.load(astring + '.npy')
    exec(astring ' =  tmp' )
```